# How to define height for page with angular-split area correctly?

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I have page with [angular-split](https://bertrandg.github.io/angular-split/#/) like this:

```
<div class="height-max">
  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
  <as-split direction="horizontal">
      <as-split-area>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </as-split-area>
      <as-split-area *ngIf="(contentSplitVisible | async)">
        <app-content></app-content>
      </as-split-area>
      <as-split-area *ngIf="(propertiesSplitVisible | async)">
        <app-properties></app-properties>
      </as-split-area>
  </as-split>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.height-max 
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

to make the split gutters visible ([see](https://github.com/bertrandg/angular-split/issues/2)). Having height 100% for the outmost element has one major drawback:

There is always a scrollbar because app-nav-menu is inside the div. The scrollbable height is height of the app-nav-menu.

I can tacle this by changing:

```
.height-max 
{
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

This in turn has drawbacks also:

- some content might become unreachable
- gutter handle is not in the center vertically

For some reason I can't specify the height-max class to a new div that wraps only as-split. So this does not work:

```
<div>
  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
  <div  class="height-max">
      <as-split direction="horizontal">
          <as-split-area>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            ...
```

How this should be done correctly?

Comment: Do you have a `stackblitz` to show?

Comment: No, but I guess I have to make one with very simple case.

Comment: I came across this exact issue in our application last year. I noticed that the splitter does not automatically account for any space used above or below the area so the height of it is actually set to the innerheight of the browser window. It only appeared to be correct but we had some buttons where we had <br> tags used and when they were taken out they would disappear from view. I discovered the reason was improper height but did not look into how to fix until this morning.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
.height-max {
height: calc(100vh - 10px);
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please create a stackblitz, I will show you how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

```
.as-horizontal .as-split-gutter {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you take some time to explain *why* this should solve the problem at hand?

Comment: Solved the issue for me with gutter not appearing even with both left and right panels having content. Not sure how/why. Setting height to either left or right panel was not an option for me. Dev seems quite cocky turning down questions about this, although there is quite a few.